# Is it possible to use curly braces in case selector in bash?

Tags: bash, case, glob, curly-braces, brace-expansion

I want to make some actions for matched lines in a case switch. And because strings are long, I wanted to use bash curly braces. But it does not work.

This code without curly braces works as expected:

```
for i in longstr_one longstr_two; do
    case $i in
    longstr_one| longstr_five)
        echo matched $i
        ;;
        *)
        echo no matches of $i
        ;;
    esac
done
```

And I got expected result:

```
matched longstr_one
no matches of longstr_two
```

But the following code with curly braces does not:

```
for i in longstr_one longstr_two; do
    case $i in
    longstr_{one|,five})
        echo matched $i
        ;;
        *)
        echo no matches of $i
        ;;
    esac
done
```

And I got incorrect result:

```
no matches of longstr_one
no matches of longstr_two
```

Why it is not working?
Is it possible to use curly braces in case selector in bash?

Comment: `case` matches based on wildcard (or "glob") patterns; brace expansions are a different thing. Your best bet might be to enable `extglob`, and use the extended glob syntax.

Comment: Alternative: Two nested `case` statements with `longstr_*)` and then `*one|*five)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since brace expansion isn't done in `case` patterns, you could use bash's extended glob syntax instead:

```
shopt -s extglob

for i in longstr_one longstr_two; do
    case $i in
    longstr_@(one|five) )
        echo "matched $i"
        ;;
        *)
        echo "no matches of $i"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

The syntax `@(this|that|theother|...)` matches any one of the subpatterns.

Answer (score 4):

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> case
>   The syntax of the case command is:
>
> ```
> case word in
>       [ [(] pattern [| pattern]…) command-list ;;]…
> esac
> ```
>
> ...
>   ... Each *pattern* undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.
>   ...

That means that [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) is not performed on `case`'s *pattern*, so it is not possible to use it here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching on the entire value of `i`, just match on the portion remaining after you remove the common prefix.

```
for i in longstr_one longstr_two; do
    case ${i#longstr_} in
    one|five)
        echo matched $i
        ;;
        *)
        echo no matches of $i
        ;;
    esac
done
```

This approach does not depend on any non-standard extensions like `extglob`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It probably may be useful for somebody. But in my case it is not applicable, because actually those longstr prefixes are all different.

Comment: Then why did you think brace expansion would be useful in the first place?

Comment: Because there is still lots of repeating. I have used a solution of Gordon Davisson and you can see my real world use case here:  https://github.com/Ashark/archlinux-amdgpu/blob/19.20-test/make_stupid_mapping.sh#L38